# Testing members of a Binary Tree

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, member

I am currently trying to traverse a Binary Tree to check if certain values are within.
A for loop is testing all values from 1 to 50 and will return true for each matched value.

here is the current tree:

```
              8
            /    \
           4      38
          / \    /  \
         3  7   31  39
        /      / \   \
       1     16  33  45

IntegerData test(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  test.value = i;
  if (bt->member(&test)) {
   cout << "member true for " << i << endl;
  }
}
```

Now I have to implement the member function and I have the right idea down, but it stops after it checks the root, root->left and root->right. I feel as if I am using the correct form of recursion, but I guess not. Here's my code:

```
bool BinaryTreeNode::member(Data * data) {
BinaryTreeNode *newNode = new BinaryTreeNode(data);
   if (data->compareTo(this->nodeData) == 0) {
       return true;
   }
   else if (data->compareTo(this->left->nodeData) == 0) {
       return true;
       newNode->member(data);
   }
   else if (data->compareTo(this->right->nodeData) == 0) {
       return true;
       newNode->member(data);
   }
   return false;
}
```

The previously stated for loop prints out

```
member true for 8
member true for 4
member true for 38
```

but nothing else.

Would someone give provide some direction via pseudo code or a script. You don't have to give me code since I wanna figure that out on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Will this always be an ordered BST as in your example?

Comment: Sweet, then I don't have to revise my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an ordered BST:

```
bfs(root) {
    if (root is null) 
        return false // if we get to leaves without finding the target, it's not there
    if (root is target value)
        return true // if we found it, then YAY
    if (root is less than target value)
        return bfs(right child) // if target > root, target must lie in right subtree
    return bfs(left child) // otherwise target < root, check left subtree
```

You only want to check wether the value at the *root* is the target value. If you check children, you're checking some of them twice (once when they are the child and once when they are the root). It also makes the code more complicated, which is probably what led to your logical error.

---

EDIT: Just found [this](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Lookup) explanation of the algorithm.

EDIT: I also want to just highlight a little mistake you made that I've seen lots of people do - calling a function that returns something but not doing anything with the return value.

The lines I'm talking about are the `newNode->member(data);` lines. There you've called the next step in the recursion, but you haven't used the result. That means your program won't *backtrace* once it finds the target lower in the tree. To use the return value in a recursive function, you MUST have `return next_call()` (in this case `return newNode->member(data);`).

Comment: that's smart. I didn't take order into consideration in mine

Comment: as per your last edit, he would have to find a way to set `newNode` in the right direction before returning the `next_call()`. With the way the control flow is setup, the code may end up looking like `if (newNode = newNode->right && newNode->member(data))`. The assumption is that the first aspect should always evaluate to some `true` form. If there is a problem with that part of the code, it would be hard to debug

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're saying. The asker should definitely set newNode in the right direction before returning the next call to avoid searching redundant parts of the tree. Also, 'newNode=newNode->right' shouldn't ever be true in a BST (nodes shouldn't be their own children).
I also don't know what you mean by 'aspect'. Is that a Ruby thing?

Comment: Well I have reached an answer. It turns out my member code was working correctly, but rather my insert code was faulty. I will shift my attention towards that. Thank you both for taking the time to help me out. I appreciate it.

Comment: Indeed. I made necessary changes so that it would function correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is a wonky implementation of a tree-traversal algorithm. But if you want to keep what you have, consider switching the position of you return statements with the statements below it.

However, this is how I would refactor your code

```
bool member(BinaryTreeNode *node, Data *data) {
   // Create wrapper for data
   BinaryTreeNode *newNode = new BinaryTreeNode(data);

   if (data->compareTo(node->nodeData) == 0) { // Check the current node only!
       return true;
   else  // delegate the rest of the tree to recursion.
       if (member(node->left,  data)) // Check the left
       || (member(this->right, data)) // Check the right
           return true;
       else
         return false;
}
```

Then again, you should test this and let me know if it works. I am coming from Ruby and I haven't programmed in C++ in a while.

Oh, and when you want to call this in your driver code, pass the root node of the binary tree as the first node. If this is a class or module function, try passing `self`. My hopes is that `self` point to the `root` node

Comment: you mean as in:
newNode->member(data);
return true; ?

I just tried that and it didn't change anything.
Any other ideas?

Comment: you may have gotten some wonky behaviour because there was no explicit call to return false if the element was not found. I fixed that.

Comment: I tried to implement this in a way that relates to my current code, but it didn't work for me. Thanks for the help though.